# How to pass object from select control to another view in django

Tags: django

I'm populating a select control in django template, but item options come from external web service which takes several time to query. There is any way to pass objects or "store" data (like jsf) in the view? I don't want request the web service to get the object instance.

Actually options are populated with object id in the value option.
I used the index of object in the array too, but I don't know what to do.

```html
<option value="{{ forloop.counter }}">
```

```html
<option value="{{ item.id }}">
```

```py
def get(self, request):
    client = ExternalServiceClient()
    products = client.all_products()
    context_data = {'product_list': products}
    return render(request, 'product-create.html', context=context_data)
```

I expect query the external service only one time by form and pass the entire object to post method view.

Comment: What all data is required in your `get()` method and where is your external API call happens?

Comment: Hi @JPG data is used to populate the dropdown and the external API call happens in client.all_products()

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you looking for. caching the view something like:

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page

@cache_page(60 * 15)# cache 15 minutes
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

why caching? that because you need to check is there any update or not. you can check here for more explanation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/cache/.

But if you dont need to check for any update, i think it's better to store to you DB and not make any request to external API every call.

Comment: Thanks @dpht how to use data in this cached view from other view? in next step I need the object selected in the dropdown list. If I get only the object id I will need query the web service but that takes several time.

Comment: can't. you need declare @cache_page decorator on every view you need. If you want to separate that call on different views maybe the best way you make table on your db for save the data from the first call. and then you make periodic task to check for data update. hope it help you.